# iPad web app - cache manifest updates, but ipad using old images

Tags: ipad, caching, web, manifest

I am developing a web app for the iPad (amongst other things) and I use the cache.manifest to load the content offline.

This has been working, but I have noticed 1 problem with the cache updates... sometimes (and I repeat this only happens sometimes) the old images I had used previously, but had replaced them about 50 cache.manifest versions ago, are still being loaded instead of the new images.

I am using the same name for the image, but the actual image has changed. Everything else seems to update (css, js, html, etc) and even most of the time the images are the more recent versions, but every once in a while (maybe 1/4 cache.manifest versions) some old images are being used again by the iPad.

I have tried clearing the data by clearing all website / cache data under settings > safari. And I have tried doing the hold power button for 5 seconds then home button for 5 seconds which supposedly clears data for the app.

While it would be useful to know how to actually clear all the data for safari / my web app off the iPad, I am looking for a more permanent solution as I hope to put this into production at some point so I would need something I can do in my coding to resolve this issue.

You can view the web app at chumpgenius.com/chump (works best in chrome!). I should mention this issue only occurs on the iPad from what I can tell. I would imagine you cannot duplicate this issue as you wouldn't ever have downloaded the old content at this point, but maybe something in my code is not working right. I have the appcache handling stuff at the bottom of index.html (view source)

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried deleting the manifest file and the attribute from the HTML tag? It's called a cache for a reason, I had the same problem, it worked for me. Best not to use a manifest until the project is complete or it will drive you nuts.

Comment: not sure if my question is still relevant, but this is good advice, not to use the manifest until the project is completed.